# What are some of the major words that we use in English directly (unmodified) from Latin?

Tags: english, reference-request

I am looking through the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_words_with_English_derivatives) on Latin words used in English, but they mostly consist of words like "lux" and "terra", words that are sort of used in English, but really have that Latin feel to them.

I am basically looking for a list of 30 Latin words that are used in English *directly*, without modification. Words like "matrix" and "vertex" are examples, they are used in math and such without modification. They are "good" words in the sense that you wouldn't have known they were from Latin as a person not into linguistics. Is there such a list anywhere? If not, what are the major words like "matrix", "vertex", "plasma", "locus", and others.

Comment: My guess is you will have more luck looking for neo-latin words. naturally those will have more technical-scientific flavor. such as: *stimulus*, *nebula*, *index*  or *sinus*. you may want to look for words that end with -us or -ex. 

There are also words that are the same but have modified meaning such as *alibi* 

However, as I'm curious of the context of your question, I would like to hear more details.

Comment: Found this list (not all words are from latin, so *caveat*! (which is another word): 
https://books.google.com/books?id=RCUEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=unique+english+plurals+index+vertex+stimulus&source=bl&ots=aN8zVkiwG7&sig=ACfU3U0t7ebkmQHDcnbJB7zPEr6Kobhqtg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhm4Psje3mAhVCElAKHZOyBU0Q6AEwCXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=unique%20english%20plurals%20index%20vertex%20stimulus&f=false

Hope those kind of words you are looking for

Comment: @d_e yep you nailed it, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Page 403 from [*Words: A User's Guide*](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ab23AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false), by Graham Pointon and Stewart Clark:
[image]
[image]